# What are the negative PINs for on the IndustrialShield M-Duino 58 Analog

Tags: arduino-mega, atmega2560

I am working as an internship on an Arduino based PLC. It is the M-Duino 58 Analog from IndustrialShields. I try to figure out how it works; Reverse Engineering. But i dont know why it has negative Digital Inputs like normal Digital Input I1.0 also has a connection -I1.0.
It is probably a simple question but i cant figure it out. Hope you guys can help me.

[image]

I guess i figured it out. Seems to be the GND connections. Should read the Manual better next time.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the cathode of an opto isolator maybe? Would need a full schematic not a pinout diagram. The manual should tell you.

Comment: Thx, i guess these are the GND connections. Did not see it when i read the manual the first time.

Comment: Yeah, I think the inputs are all opto-isolated - so the input is actually a resistor and LED, with the "input" being the anode and the "-" being the cathode. It's hard to find any real information though, documentation seems to be a little poor.

Comment: The Manufacturer's documentation is at https://www.industrialshields.com/technical-features-industrial-m-duino-plc-arduino-ethernet-58-ios-analog-digital-plus

Answer (score 1):

It looks like those inputs are opto-isolated. That means that the "input" goes through a resistor and the internal LED of an opto-isolator, which then comes back out of the "-" pin:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f24D5A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So "-" connects to the ground of the remote device, and the "input" connects to the signal.